# Derive the LLN for a certain sequence

Tags: self-study, correlation, variance, random-variable, independence

I have a sequence of dependent random variables $X_1, X_2...X_n$. Each RV is correlated with two other RVs and uncorrelated with the others.The ones that are correlated satisfy the condition $Cov(X_i,X_j) \le \frac{1}{n^2}$

I need to:

1. Derive an upper bound on the variance of the sample mean $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{X_i}{n}$
2. Derive a version of the LLN for the sequence

I'm not really sure where to start with this. I do know that the LLN says that as $n$ approaches infinity, the sample mean will approach $E(X)$, the expected value of the RV. But I don't understand how to derive a "version of it for this sequence, or even what "version" means here. I also don't know how to find an upper bound for the variance. We have used concentration inequalities to bound the sample mean... would I just somehow extend one of those (like Chebyshev's?) to apply to the variance?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: 
$$\operatorname{var}\left(\sum_{i=n}^n X_i\right)
= \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{var}(X_i)
+ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1; j \neq i}^n \operatorname{cov}(X_i,X_j)\tag{1}$$
How many terms in that double sum on the right are nonzero?
What is the maximum value that these terms can have?

---

The question is very poorly formulated and both parts do not necessarily have
an answer.

> Assume that $n$ is a *fixed* number.

We are given that $X_i, 1 \leq i \leq n$ are *dependent* random variables
such that each $X_i$ is correlated with $2$ other $X_j$ but uncorrelated
with all the others. Furthermore, both of the two nonzero covariances
$\operatorname{cov}(X_i,X_{j_{1}})$ and  $\operatorname{cov}(X_i,X_{j_{2}})$ 
are no larger than $n^{-2}$. (Curiously, this upper bound on the covariances
does not involve the variances of the random variables at all, and thus seems
more like a bound on the (Pearson) correlation coefficients).
So the $n\times n$ *covariance* matrix
$C$ with entries $C_{i,j} = \operatorname{cov}(X_i,X_{j})$ has
*three* nonzero entries in each row: one entry (on the diagonal)
being a variance and the other two off-diagonal entries being at most
$n^{-2}$.

*Can* such a covariance matrix exist?  Yes, for example, suppose that
only the following pairs of random variables are correlated:
$$(X_1,X_2),~ (X_2,X_3),~ (X_3,X_4),~ \ldots,~ (X_{n-1},X_n),~ (X_n,X_1).$$
The covariance matrix in this case is a tri-diagonal matrix with two
additional nonzero entries at $(n,1)$ and $(1,n)$. Note, however,
that this correlation structure cannot be *expanded* to include
a $(n+1)$-th random variabe $X_{n+1}$.

So, applying what was hinted at above in $(1)$, we get that
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}\left(\sum_{i=n}^n X_i\right)
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{var}(X_i)
+ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1; j \neq i}^n \operatorname{cov}(X_i,X_j)\\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{var}(X_i) + 2n\cdot n^{-2}
&{\scriptstyle{\text{only}~2n~\text{terms are nonzero}}}\\
\operatorname{var}\left(\sum_{i=n}^n X_i\right)
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{var}(X_i) + \frac{2}{n}\tag{2}\\
\operatorname{var}\left(\frac 1n\sum_{i=n}^n X_i\right)
&\leq \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{var}(X_i) + \frac{2}{n^3}\tag{3}
\end{align}$$
and if all the random variables have the same variance $\sigma^2$, then
$$\operatorname{var}\left(\frac 1n\sum_{i=n}^n X_i\right)
\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \frac{2}{n^3}.\tag{4}$$
This result is also found in @AlecosPapadopoulos's answer to this question.

Returning to $(1)$, note that variances are nonnegative numbers, and thus
it must be that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1; j \neq i}^n \operatorname{cov}(X_i,X_j)
\geq -\sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{var}(X_i).\tag{5}$$
Since there are only $2n$ nonzero terms on the left side of $(5)$,
the *average* of the $2n$ nonzero covariances is bounded below
by the negative of *half* the average variance. For the special
case of all variances being $\sigma^2$ and all the nonzero
covariances being equal, we have the peculiar result that
$$-\frac{\sigma^2}{2} \leq \operatorname{cov}(X_i,X_j) \leq \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

---

Things are equally strange when one tries to derive a Law of Large
Numbers type result in this schema and so we are looking at
increasing values of $n$ instead of just a fixed integer value. 
Assume without loss of
generality that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are correlated, and thus
$$\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_2) \leq \frac{1}{n^2}.$$
Since this must hold whether we are looking at $n=10$ or $n=100$
or $n=1000$ etc., we conclude that the *upper bound* on the
nonzero correlations must be $0$, and since these covariances
are *supposed* to be nonzero, it must be that all the nonzero
covariances are strictly negative numbers. The alternative,
that the $X_1$ and $X_2$ in the list $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{10}$
are not the same as the $X_1$ and $X_2$ in the list
$X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{100}$ is too dreadful to contemplate.
There is also the issue of what the covariance matrix looks like
since the structure described above cannot be extended. As
noted in Alecos's answer, we need to modify the statement that
"each random variable is correlated with exactly two other
random variables" to something like "each random variable
(with the possible exception of one or two) is correlated
with exactly two other random variables".  And of course,
in the absence of any information about the *variances*
of the random variables, we cannot guarantee any kind of
law of large numbers result. $\operatorname{var}(X_i)$
being *finite* for all $i$ is insufficient; we need the
variance of the sample mean to approach $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @DilipSarwate hint,

$$\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac 1n\sum_{i=n}^n X_i\right)
=\frac 1{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{var}(X_i)
+ \frac 1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1; j \neq i}^n \operatorname{cov}(X_i,X_j)$$

We have to determine carefully the number of non-zero covariances. We are told:

> "Each RV is correlated with two other RVs and uncorrelated with the
>   others"

This means that, e.g., $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are correlated *between them*, and *none* of the three is correlated with any other variable. So we have subsets of three random variables each providing in total *six* covariance terms, because each pair-wise covariance appears *twice* in the double sum.

This affects the total number of non-zero covariance depending on whether $n$ is exactly divisible by $3$, or not.

Assume first that $n$ is exactly divisible by $3$. Then the total number of non zero covariances is $6\cdot \frac n3 = 2n $

Then

$$\frac 1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1; j \neq i}^n \operatorname{cov}(X_i,X_j) \leq \frac 1{n^2}\cdot 2n\cdot \frac 1{n^2} = \frac 2{n^3} \tag{1}$$

Assume now that we increase $n$ by $1$. All variables up to index $n$ (which is divisible by three exactly), have exhausted their non-zero covariances between them, so the last variable cannot be correlated with any other variable. So we conclude that in this case, the upper bound for the covariance-double sum is the same.

Finally assume that now $n$ is such that division by three leaves $2$ as remainder. Using the same logic as before, we conclude that two more non-zero covariance terms appear (two times the covariance of the two "additional" random variables). Denote this $n_2 = n+2$. Then the non-zero covariance terms here are $2n +2 = 2(n+1)$, and the upper bound for the covariance term becomes

$$\frac 1{n_2^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n_2} \sum_{j=1; j \neq i}^{n_2} \operatorname{cov}(X_i,X_j) \leq \frac 1{n_2^2}\cdot 2(n+1)\cdot \frac 1{n_2^2} = \frac {2(n+1)}{(n+2)^4} \tag{2}$$

It is easy to check that the right-hand side of $(2)$ is smaller than the right-hand side of $(1)$ and so we conclude that for any finite $n$, the upper bound for the variance of the sample mean is

$$\sup_n\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac 1n\sum_{i=n}^n X_i\right) = \frac {\operatorname{var}(X)}{n} + \frac{2}{n^3}$$

(where we have assumed identical marginal distributions), since more over the sum-of-variances term declines with $n$.

Then a "version" of the Weak Law of Large Numbers would go

$$\Big\{E(\bar X_n) = E(X),\;\; \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sup_n\operatorname{Var}\left(\bar X_n\right) = 0\Big\} \Rightarrow \bar X_n \xrightarrow{p} E(X)$$

Comment: More simply, the $n\times n$ covariance matrix of the $X_i$'s has (at most) three nonzero entries on each row, one of which is the variance of $X_i$ and the other two the covariances which are smaller than $\frac{1}{n^2}$. Thus, there are at most $2n$ nonzero covariances and we get the right side of $(1)$ as the maximum possible value of the double sum being looked at.